# Do the properties of modular arithmetic apply to incongruent relations?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

Can you treat incongruences as you would congruent relations?
i.e. do the following theorems still apply?

[image: Rosen 149]

As an example, let's say you wanted to prove Euclid's Lemma which states:

> If a prime $p$ divides the product $ab$ of two integers $a$ and $b$, then $p$ must divide at least one of those integers $a$ or $b$.

If we can show that $p\not\mid a,b$ implies that $p\not\mid ab$ then we have proven the contrapositive and thus our original statement. So, assume that $p\not\mid a,b$. Then by the definition of congruences,

$$a\not\equiv 0\ (mod\ p)$$
$$b\not\equiv 0\ (mod\ p)$$

If (iii) from Theorem 4.6 still holds then it follows that
$$ab\not\equiv 0\ (mod\ p)$$

hence $p\not\mid ab$ as desired.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean.  Consider:   $1\not\equiv 2 \pmod p$ and $2\not \equiv 1 \pmod p$ but $1\times 2\equiv 2\times 1\pmod p$.  Is that a counterexample to what you were hoping for?

Comment: If $p\not|a,b$ then $p\not|ab$ when $p$ is prime but there are counterexamples when $p$ is composite (such as $p=6, a=3, b=4$)

Answer (score 1):

This is weak. (iii) is a case of selection. in any base ( even greater than 4) $$2\cdot 1 \equiv (-1)\cdot (-2)$$  Despite, no parts being congruent. The theorem above is simply the inverse of the 0 product rule. In the absence of zero divisors ( divisor of 0 in a ring etc forming a product of 0 with another non zero element) it is true, in the presence of 0 divisors it is not.